# too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop sliders

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a slider that when it moves to assign some value it throws the erros of

```
Invariant Violation:Toomany re-renders
```

this is the code

```
    const [term, setvterm] = useState();

if( Value > 0) setvterm(Value)

<View style={{alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Slider 
    maximumValue={D > 0 ? 3: 2 }
    minimumValue={0}
    step={1}
    value={valuesFromApi.indexOf(Value)}
    onValueChange={index => setValue(valuesFromApi[index])} 
    />
    <View style={styles.plazos}>
    <Text style={styles.plazo1}>{A} meses</Text>
    <Text style={styles.plazo2}>{B} meses</Text>
    <Text style={styles.plazo3}>{C} meses</Text>
    {D > 0 ? <Text style={styles.plazo3}>{D} meses</Text>: null }
    </View>
    <Text style={styles.slideText}>Su credito por:  ${A}MXN</Text>
    <Text style={styles.slideText}>Usted recibe:    ${A}MXN</Text>
    <Text style={styles.slideText}>A un plazo de:  {Value} meses</Text>

    <Text style={styles.PaymentText}>Su pago: ${A}.00 MXN</Text>
</View>
```

i m sure the problem is here

```
   if( Value > 0) setvterm(Value)
```

but thats the only way that i found to pass the value of Value to terms

Comment: Yes, you have an infinite rendering loop since you update state each render. You likely need an `useEffect` hook to issue side-effect when `Value` updates. What is `terms`?

Comment: terms is nothing at that point, but that is the variable name that i have to send to an api

Comment: Isn't `if( Value > 0) setvterm(Value)` inside the `setValue` function?

Comment: You can use deal with this with something like: `if (Value > 0 && Value !== term) { setvterm(value)) }`

Answer (score 0):

That type of error occurs when you have an infinite loop of setting values, rendering, then setting the value again, and so on. The solution is to ensure that you only re-render if the value has changed. You will need to track the previous value. Here's an article explaining how to do that: https://medium.com/@hegystyle/remembering-the-previous-value-of-a-prop-or-a-state-while-using-react-hooks-6f57686aa0a6